# Why does not google let me view the next search result pages?

Tags: google, google-search

Why does not google let me view the next search result pages, although the keyword fetched 50 pages of results, BUT it only take me till 5th page and there is no other option to move ahead. However, when I see on the top it says **"Page 5 of 50 results"**

Comment: Your question would be better suited for Web Applications, but you'll need to make it clearer what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Page 5 of 50 **results**"

That is 50 *results*, not pages. With 10 results per page (the default), you are already on the last page.